# Hibernate Optimistic Locking Exception on MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, postgresql

Migrating Hibernate to a `MySQL`(as of this question version `5.6.23`)  database from `PostgreSQL` started throwing `OptimisticLockingException'`s in all our database transactions, everything that was working perfectly in PostgreSQL stopped working. I found the problem that was causing this to happen and am documenting for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate provides optimistic locking via the Version function. This can either be a numeric field or a `timestamp`. I used the `@Version` annotation to provide both optimistic locking and dateModication on my entities, after some [digging](http://www.outjected.com/blog/2009/12/29/hibernate-optimistic-locking-and-mySQL.html) I found that MySQL [stores date/time without millisecond precision](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8523). So as soon MySQL encounters `@Version` on the a timestamp column it blows up on the updates, I am very disappointed that MySQL has still not opted to support such a basic thing even after repeated requests and bug reports.